# linear regression converge but the result is not good

Tags: c, machine-learning, linear-regression

Important : i'm a beginner in ML and i want to implement, by myself, the algorithms i'm learning, without using ML libraries.

I have a dataset with the price (y) for the number of km (x), and i want to find the function that describe datas.
You can find the dataset and the entire code here : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/034d9918f6d29268f06be45d76e156f420190330174420/6af73b

I'm using a classic gradient descent algorithm : my code works and converge well for some single linear regression problems, but not the one that interest me.

```
/* Classic gradient descent algorithm */

ft_sum(double *x, double *y, long double theta0, long double theta1, int epoch, int truth)
{
    long double     result = 0.00;
    long double     tmp;
    int             i;

    i = 0;
    while (epoch--)
       {
         /* Derivative part of the gradient descent */
        tmp = ((x[i] * theta1 + theta0)) - (y[i]);
        if (truth == 1)
            tmp = tmp * (x[i]);
        result += tmp;
        i++;
    }
    return (result);
}

/* Linear regression */

void        single_linear_regression(double *x, double *y, double epoch, char *argv)
{
    long double     theta0 = 0; /* bias */
    long double     theta1 = 0; /* weight */
    long double     error = 100; /* Cost of the function */
    long double     tmp1;
    long double     tmp2;
    double          alpha = 0.0000000001; /* with higher learning rate it does not converge */
    int             i = 0;

    while (!(error > -0.4 && error < 0.4)) // it doesn't go below 0.4
    {
        tmp1 = theta0 - ((alpha * (1.00 / epoch) *
            (error = ft_sum(x, y, theta0, theta1, epoch - 1, 0))));
        tmp2 = theta1 - ((alpha * (1.00 / epoch) *
                (error = ft_sum(x, y, theta0, theta1, epoch - 1, 1))));
        theta0 = tmp1;
        theta1 = tmp2;
        printf("error := %Lf\n", error);
    }
    printf("error := %Lf | theta0 == %Lf | theta1 == %Lf\n", error, theta0, theta1);
}
```

At the end, i have :

error := 0.240723 | theta0 == 0.000004 | theta1 == 0.044168

(f(x) = 0.044x + 0.000004)
When the actual function is : -0.02x + 8500...

I have already tried normalizing datas [0-1], changing starting values of the weight and the bias, and i'm really stuck on this.

Comment: The link will not allow me to download your data without agreeing to some legal agreement, and I'm not a lawyer. Can you try a less restrictive download service?

Comment: Yup, sorry, you can find it here : https://github.com/nabboufe/Linear_Regression

Comment: I visually inspected a scatterplot of the data, and it appears to me a straight line is likely the best model you can make with this data.

Comment: Well, this is why I'm using linear regression. Do you know why my algorithm converge but not at the expected value ?

Comment: When I fit your data to a straight line using linear regression, rather than iterative gradient descent, the fitted values are very near those you posted for "actual".

Comment: Well.. this is why i'm here : to know what is missing with my algorithm, or what i do wrong, i already know this dataset can converge correctly, just don't know why with my algorithm it doesn't. I know i can use some library that do all the work for you, better than if i did (and compared to what i already did...), but for some pedagogic reasons, i want to do this by my own.

Comment: I understand, and I propose a test to determine of the specific problem in this case is due to the initial parameters used to start the "descent" in error space. First, try with the known parameter values - that should succeed, and verifies the beginning of the test. Second, try with each initial parameter value an average of the posted and known correct parameter values - does that work properly? Finally, try with values very close to the known good parameters, such as rounding the good values to the nearest whole number.